# How to get id of dynamic looped element for record clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have records that are being looped through and sent to the html file via `json_encode`. For each record, I have a data-attribute that I am storing the record id. What I am trying to accomplish is when the user clicks "Edit" (`.recEdit`) then I can obtain the id (`data-recId`). I am trying to do this with a click function, utilizing the `$(this)` and `parent()` functions.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the looped code from the php file:

```
$html .= '<div class="recentProjectCont" data-recId="'.$recProjId.'">';
$html .= '<div class="recProjInfoCont">';
$html .= '<div class="recInfoCont1">';
$html .= '<span class="recProjName recBaseFormat">'.$recProjName.'</span>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div class="recInfoCont2">';
$html .= '<span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat">'.$recProjStat.'</span>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div class="recEdit">Edit</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
```

Then the click function where I am attempting to obtain the id.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.recEdit' ,function() {
    var projID = $(this).parent().data('recId');
    console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of `data` attributes get normalised to lowercase in jQuery's internal cache, so you need to use `data('recid')` instead of `data('recId')`

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.recEdit', function() {
  var projID = $(this).parent().data('recid');
  console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recentProjectCont" data-recId="$recProjId">
  <div class="recProjInfoCont">
    <div class="recInfoCont1">
      <span class="recProjName recBaseFormat">$recProjName</span>
    </div>
    <div class="recInfoCont2">
      $html
      <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat">$recProjStat</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recEdit">Edit</div>
  $html
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this did the trick!

Comment: Certainly the case normalization has been noticed previously...?

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, it hasn't given me any issues with anything I have done thus far.

Comment: Didn't realise I had a reputation :) You're right, this should have been closed a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stick to using `$(this)`, you can try to provide `onClick` handler function like this:

```
function(event) {
  var projID = $(event.target).parent().data('recId');
  console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted considering it's syntactically broken, and a big step backwards in terms of best practice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan using jquery is a big step backwards in terms of best practice

Comment: That's arguable. However using inline `onclick` attributes is not what anyone should be doing.

Comment: That's arguable - modern framewroks like angular bind handlers in html templates. In pure js, especially for small pages this is acceptable. For big pages, people use frameworks...

Answer (score -2):

You can change a little your approach in this way - change before last php line to

```
$html .= '<div class="recEdit" onclick="clicked('.$recProjId.')">Edit</div>';
```

Then remove jquery handler and add simple

```
function clicked(projID) { 
    console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);
}
```

```js
function clicked(projID) {
  console.log('Project ID is..... ' + projID);
}
```

```css
.recEdit{ padding: 10px; background: #fdf; width: 30px; cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<div class="recentProjectCont" data-recId="666">
  <div class="recProjInfoCont">
    <div class="recInfoCont1">
      <span class="recProjName recBaseFormat">My-project</span>
    </div>
    <div class="recInfoCont2">
      <span class="recInfoStat recBaseFormat">stat_123</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recEdit" onclick="clicked(666)">Edit</div>
</div>
```